# Why is the second fade in not working?

Tags: jquery, fadein, fade, fadeout

I'm trying to fade one image to second on mouse enter and reverse on mouse leave.
The effect I want can be found at http://mango.com any of their product images. Here's the script below.

```
<div id="fade">
    <img src="two.gif" width="100" height="100" id="two1" class="after" style="display:none;"/>
    <img src="one.gif" width="100" height="100" id="one1" class="before" />
</div>
<div id="fade">
    <img src="two.gif" width="100" height="100" id="two2" class="after" style="display:none;" />
    <img src="one.gif" width="100" height="100" id="one2" class="before" style="" />
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#one1,#one2').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).fadeOut(500);
    $(this).prev('img').fadeIn(500);
});
$('#two1,#two2').mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).fadeOut(500);
    $(this).prev('img').fadeIn(500);
});
</script>
```

It fades once but next time both images disappear. Please can anyone post the code or give reference to any code/plugin that works the same.

Comment: make sure no two/more DOM elements have **same** `id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where you have

```
$('#two1,#two2').mouseleave(function(){
$(this).fadeOut(500);
$(this).prev('img').fadeIn(500);
});
```

You should have

```
$('#two1,#two2').mouseleave(function(){
$(this).fadeOut(500);
$(this).next('img').fadeIn(500);
});
```

You've just forgotten to switch "next" for "prev" on the mouseleave.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
$('#one1,#one2').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).fadeOut(500);
    $(this).parent().find('.after').fadeIn(500);
});

$('#two1,#two2').mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).fadeOut(500);
    $(this).parent().find('.before').fadeIn(500);
});
```

Example at http://jsfiddle.net/g5XF2/

Answer (score 1):

Use next() instead of prev() in mouseleave event functioanality

```
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $('#one1,#one2').mouseenter(function()
            {
                $(this).fadeOut(500);
                $(this).prev('img').fadeIn(500);
            });

            $('#two1,#two2').mouseleave(function()
            {
                $(this).fadeOut(500);
                $(this).next('img').fadeIn(500);
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#one1,#one2').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).fadeOut(500, function() {
       $(this).prev('img').fadeIn(500);
    });

});
$('#two1,#two2').mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).fadeOut(500, function() {
      $(this).next('img').fadeIn(500);
    });
});​
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qytkS/2/)